# Can't upload program to Arduino Leonardo from Mac

Tags: macos, arduino

I'm new to programming Arduino boards. I have an Arduino Leonardo with Headers and I'm trying to upload a program to it. I've been getting this error:

> avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: exit bootloader

Here's my Build Options:

[image]

I'm assuming my Port or Programmer isn't configured correctly. What should the Port and Programmer be? Do I need to install a driver?

Comment: Well Bluetooth seems unlikely to be correct! So change the port to `/dev/somethingelse` according to what is available in the Port menu.

Comment: "dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port" is the only option that shows up. How can I get different options?

Comment: You may have been sold a cheap Chinese clone of the Leonardo which has a CH340 (?) chip instead of the FTI chip and, as far as I know, there is no driver for macOS that works. If anyone knows better, please ping me using @MarkSetchell

Comment: ... further to my earlier comment, can you try attaching it to a Linux PC to see if it works there and to detect the chip? Linux boxes support the cheap clones whereas Macs do not.

Comment: I bought the Leonardo on Arduino's website, so I hope it's not a cheap clone. I'll work on finding a Linux PC to test on next

Comment: @MarkSetchell Leonardo has native USB support. There is no CH340 or FTDI chip.

Comment: @gre_gor Thank you for sharing your knowledge - I was unaware of that and hence didn't put it as an answer, just an idea in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Port

You should select port of serial communication with your board. It should look like this (I have connected Arduino UNO):

[image: port]

### Programmer

In regular case programmer selection is irelevant. Arduino IDE uses programmer only if you want it. So if you want to upload your code with usb cable, you do not need to care about it.

[image: programmer]

### Drivers

If you are sure, that your cable is working and Arduino port is not in the list of ports in Arduino IDE, you should install **FTDI drivers**. To install

1. Head over to the [FTDI Chip drivers page](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm)
2. Scroll down a little to find the table of download links. Find your computer operating system in the list and select the appropriate download link
3. Download the driver to your computer
4. Open the installer DMG file
5. Open the **FTDIUSBSerial.pkg** file. This will open an installer dialog box. Click continue through the main windows, and agree to terms of software license agreement to install
6. Enter your admin password. Click Install Software. Wait while install processes. Installation should be successful.

Comment: The only option I have in Ports is "dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port", how do I get my Arduino port as an option?

Comment: @JanČerný A Leonardo has no FTDI chip.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Jan Černý](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7274239/jan-%C4%8Cern%C3%BD) for the detailed response.

The actual solution to my problem however was getting the right cable. I was using a micro usb cable that must have been charge only.

Anyway, I bought one of [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00UFG5GVM) and the correct Port showed up.